# Android how to add a fixed tab on SlidingTabStrip which will not scroll horizintally

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am using SlidingTabStrip on my project on the bottom.
But i need a fixed tab which will not scroll horizontally.
But the other items will be scroll horizontal.

Here i include my design what i need:

[image]

[image]

I also tried with a Linearlayout and SlidingTabStrip but I do not want to select any item of tab strip when i click on home. Also when i click on tab strip item then selected item's fragment will populate.

Need some help how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

In SlidingTabLayout set

```
 setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```